# I want to open a program by JavaScript on the clients computer? (WScript.shell)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I tried to open a program using this code:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function run() {
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
        if (shell) {
            shell.run('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\BitTorrent\\BitTorrent.exe"', 1);
        }
        else
        { alert("BitTorrent is not installed on your system."); }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="run()">

</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work.
Any help, please?

Comment: Internet would be a really scary place if that would be possible to do that easy.

Comment: Ideally you would develop a browser plugin for this

Comment: I like how `BitTorrent` isn't installed in yoru system if `ActiveX` fails to instantiate `WScript.shell`

Comment: @Max: Starting local applications is pretty easy when done right. Ever used Skype, Spotify, iTunes, Telnet or any other tool using a custom protocol handler that is not handled by the browser itself?

Comment: @0xA3: Yes, the only difference is that all of that examples you gave require user to **manually** install something beforehand.

Comment: @Max: And having a bittorrent client on your PC requires you what? Exactly, and the clients that I know actually register a protocol handler, too.

Answer (score 1):

It is because browser block creation of ActiveX controls, for security reasons. Moreover, ActiveX is supported only in IE; IE has options to allow run ActiveX in browser, but I have doubts that many users have this feature enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to open [BitTorrent](http://www.bittorrent.com/) anyways? I believe you can achieve the desired effect using [magnet links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme)

PD: Check their [developers page](http://www.utorrent.com/developers)

Update: I'm not sure if this is "legal" here, or considered "spam", if it easy please remove it, but here's a link to a site that implements magnet links to achieve what I think you might want to be doing: [eztv.it](http://www.eztv.it). Check their [image: magnet links]

Answer (score 0):

Check your browsers' configuration, it may block ActiveX.

Do you get any error message ?

Comment: No I don't get any errors, it is just a blank page. I am using Mozilla Firefox.